# code tag not wrap content automatic, width has exceed parent's width

Tags: css

MDN said `code` is a inline element, I think it should be wrap into a new line when one line cannot hold

But my html

[image]

`chaochaogege.com/filecatcher/common/` width has exceed parent element

**Why it not wrap automatic?**

If I add following css to code tag

```
code{
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

it works.

[image]

code tag has scroll bar now

**Repeat my question**

Why code tag (a inline element) not wrap automatic?

I tried many ways, But don't works

Comment: did you tried to use `word-wrap: break-word;`?

Comment: it has nothing to do with code tag, it will be the same with any tag .. you are using a long word without space and this is the default behavior, the browser will not break it

Comment: @Jin  Yes, It works, I will  learn it..  css it so complex for new hand, it has so many propertes,..

Comment: @TemaniAfif ok, I will remember you have said. But why did you know these knowledge? I am a new hand, and don't know how to solve these problem..I have not systematically studied it and I don’t know the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `word-wrap : break-word` in css

Comment: simple and powerful! Thankyou.

Comment: @toffee don't forget to test this on Firefox too. not as powerful as you may think

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right, I have test on latest ff, it not works. From MDN browser compatibility, ff only support `keep-all`. it said we can use overflow-wrap.
So I tried `overflow-wrap:break-wrap`, it works on chrome and ff.

Comment: brilliant. keep going. :)